# React-Bootstrap Breadcrumbs throwing invalid hook call error

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have attempted to use Bootstrap breadcrumbs in my test project but constantly coming up against errors.  I have just re-written the page from a component class to a function and still get the same error.

The dreaded error I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    React 2
    useBootstrapPrefix ThemeProvider.js:29
    Breadcrumb Breadcrumb.js:20
    React 12
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 2
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:417
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:390
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:157
    js scheduler.development.js:180
    js scheduler.development.js:645
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 20
react.development.js:1476
The above error occurred in the <Breadcrumb> component:

../../node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Breadcrumb.js/Breadcrumb<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_react-bootstrap_esm_Breadcrumb_js.chunk.js:1162:7
Breadcrumbs
div
div
div
EditStudentBS@http://localhost:3000/static/js/src_pages_EditStudentBS_js.chunk.js:36:74
Suspense
Routes@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35775:7
Router@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35712:7
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35189:7
App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Source Code - Full project in link
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-galois-n7pps

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Breadcrumb } from 'react-bootstrap';

const EditStudentBS = () => {
    let props = useParams();
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [course, setCourse] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    // Handle the changes of the form fields into state
    let HandleInput = (e) => {
        switch (e.target.name) {
            case 'name':
                setName(e.target.value);
                break;
            case 'course':
                setCourse(e.target.value);
                break;
            case 'email':
                setEmail(e.target.value);
                break;
            case 'phone':
                setPhone(e.target.value);
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props);
        const FetchData = async (StudentID) => {
            const Resp = await axios.get(
                `http://localhost/api/edit-student/${StudentID}`
            );

            if (Resp.data.status === '200') {
                setName(Resp.data.student.name);
                setCourse(Resp.data.student.course);
                setEmail(Resp.data.student.email);
                setPhone(Resp.data.student.phone);
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };

        const StudentID = props.id;
        FetchData(StudentID);
        // console.log(StudentID, this.props);
    }, [props]);

    // Update student function, posts via AXIOS to the Laravel backend
    let UpdateStudent = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const StudentID = this.props.params.id;
        setIsLoading(true);
        const Resp = await axios.put(
            `http://localhost/api/update-student/${StudentID}`,
            this.state
        );
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (Resp.data.status === '200') {
            console.log(Resp.data.message);
        }
    };

    const Breadcrumbs = () => {
        return (
            <Breadcrumb>
                <Breadcrumb.Item>Students</Breadcrumb.Item>
                <Breadcrumb.Item active>Edit Students</Breadcrumb.Item>
            </Breadcrumb>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <Breadcrumbs />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-header">
                            <h4>
                                Edit Student - {name}
                                <Link
                                    to={'/'}
                                    className="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end"
                                >
                                    Back
                                </Link>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            {isLoading ? (
                                <h2>Loading...</h2>
                            ) : (
                                <form onSubmit={UpdateStudent}>
                                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                                        <label>Student Name</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="name"
                                            value={name}
                                            onChange={HandleInput}
                                            className="form-control"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                                        <label>Student Course</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="course"
                                            value={course}
                                            onChange={HandleInput}
                                            className="form-control"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                                        <label>Student Email</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="email"
                                            value={email}
                                            onChange={HandleInput}
                                            className="form-control"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                                        <label>Student Phone</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="phone"
                                            value={phone}
                                            onChange={HandleInput}
                                            className="form-control"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                                        <button
                                            type="submit"
                                            className="btn btn-primary"
                                        >
                                            Update
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default EditStudentBS;
```

Comment: Other than that the `Breadcrumbs` component should be declared *outside* of the `EditStudentBS` component, I don't see any issue. I'm unable to reproduce any errors in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-breadcrumbs-throwing-invalid-hook-call-error-0s3wi).

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, could this be because it is behind react router?  I'll create a full sanbox and update the post with the link

Comment: Dunno. I had to import and render a `Router` (`react-router-dom` v6) so the `Link` had a routing context, and didn't see any errors, but if you're able to create a CSB and reproduces the issue then we'll have something to inspect/debug.

Comment: @DrewReese I've copied the entire source over to code sandbox and just getting a white page which no errors, checked the code locally and it loads the app but still shows the error with the Breadcrumb

Comment: Your CSB loads a "students data" page with "add student" and a list of 2 with buttons to edit, edit bs, and delete. No errors though. Does the error occur when just loading the app, or do you have to interact with anything? What are the reproduction steps?

Comment: @DrewReese click on the editbs button, this should load the edit page with the breadcrumbs on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240598/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-neo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out your code/project was missing the `react-bootstrap` package. It wasn't listed in the `package.json` file in your linked codesandbox and had to be manually added there.

To add locally for your project, run from the project directory:

```
npm i -s react-bootstrap
```

This will install the current version of `react-bootstrap` and add/save it to the `package.json` dependencies section.

Comment: *face-palm* nice one that's fixed the issue!